# SVG picture is returning black image in flutter inspite of giving a color image from assests

Tags: image, svg, flutter

here is the code where i m going to add the svgpicture but i m getting black image
    new Container
                          child:  new SvgPicture.asset('assets/camera.svg')
                        ),

this is mine camera.svg file

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="13.607" height="13.608" viewBox="0 0 13.607 13.608">
    <defs>
        <style>
            .cls-1{}
        </style>
    </defs>
    <g id="Group_5" data-name="Group 5" transform="translate(-57.8 -130.498)">
        <g id="Group_4" data-name="Group 4">
            <g id="Group_3" data-name="Group 3">
                <path id="Path_2" d="M69.415 139.294a6.792 6.792 0 0 0-2.586-1.621 3.933 3.933 0 1 0-4.452 0 6.814 6.814 0 0 0-4.577 6.433h1.063a5.741 5.741 0 1 1 11.481 0h1.063a6.763 6.763 0 0 0-1.992-4.812zM64.6 137.3a2.87 2.87 0 1 1 2.87-2.87 2.874 2.874 0 0 1-2.87 2.87z" class="cls-1" data-name="Path 2"/>
            </g>
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: I don't get quite well your question. The image is returning black? but it actually is a camera picture ?

Comment: It is a downloaded svg picture which i m going to add in my code using flutter_svg, but while inserting it returns a black image.

Answer (score 44):

This is probably happened because of the corrupted SVG files from the internet. I faced this problem earlier and tried many ways to solve it. But finally, I solved it with the help of this software, [**svgcleaner**](https://github.com/RazrFalcon/svgcleaner).

Download the application into your OS, from [***here***](https://github.com/RazrFalcon/svgcleaner-gui/releases)

After installation,

1. import your SVG.

[image: importsvg]

2. Click run.

[image: run]

3. Success! Here you can see your SVGs' cleaned successfully.

[image: success]

After cleaning, you can grab those SVG files from the output folder location and add those files into your flutter app without seeing any black coloured SVG.

It works perfectly fine for me.

[image]

Comment: This tool is very helpful. In fact, if it gives an error while trying to parse the SVG, this is exactly what's causing problems with the SvgPicture widget. Click on the red cross (on the image it's a green checkmark) and fix the issue. In my case, it was `rgba(0,0,0,0)` that was causing the issue.

Answer (score 22):

[flutter_svg](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_svg) can not understand [Internal or Embedded CSS](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/types-of-css-cascading-style-sheet/).

Hence you need to remove the internal css and write inline css.

Example:-
`<path style="fill:#566e83;" ...`

Comment: Happened to me on AI export with default settings. 'Presentation attributes' styling option fixed it.

Comment: I'm using `svgo` to optimize/shrink the SVGs and it worked now. https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/svgo

Answer (score 17):

Use https://vecta.io/nano
It can remove the unsupported tags such as  and compress the svg file at certain level

Answer (score 6):

this is cause of inline css .....

```
 <style>
        .cls-1{}
    </style>
```

remove this lines and try ... your problem will be solved... flutter svg cant read inline CSS

Answer (score 3):

Edit the `style` like I did below in order to change the color:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="13.607" height="13.608" viewBox="0 0 13.607 13.608" style="fill: #ff0000;">
    <defs>
        <style>
            .cls-1{}
        </style>
    </defs>
    <g id="Group_5" data-name="Group 5" transform="translate(-57.8 -130.498)">
        <g id="Group_4" data-name="Group 4">
            <g id="Group_3" data-name="Group 3">
                <path id="Path_2" d="M69.415 139.294a6.792 6.792 0 0 0-2.586-1.621 3.933 3.933 0 1 0-4.452 0 6.814 6.814 0 0 0-4.577 6.433h1.063a5.741 5.741 0 1 1 11.481 0h1.063a6.763 6.763 0 0 0-1.992-4.812zM64.6 137.3a2.87 2.87 0 1 1 2.87-2.87 2.874 2.874 0 0 1-2.87 2.87z" class="cls-1" data-name="Path 2"/>
            </g>
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: i have edited my question with my camera.svg file,but i m not getting ur solution to do,pls help me with further steps.

Comment: Of course with pleasure, please take a look on the code that I provided, I changed the color with `style="fill: #ff0000;"`

Comment: If you "Run the code snippet" of my example, you will see the logo in red now.

Comment: :: My pleasure, @john if this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: I needed to omit the entire part so the problem disappeared : <defs>
        <style>
            .cls-1{}
        </style>
    </defs>

Answer (score 3):

**First** using the **svg** image you have provided I'm getting the following an error on the console

> I/flutter ( 7705): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY SVG
>   ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
>   I/flutter ( 7705): The following UnimplementedError was thrown in
>   parseSvgElement: I/flutter ( 7705): The  element is not
>   implemented in this library.

You can remove this section on the image to resolve that issue:

.cls-1{}

**Second**, the image is being displayed properly, just verify you have added the proper assets registration on **pubspec.yaml** file, as follow.

> assets:
>     - assets/camera.svg

Which means you have a folder called assets at a root level.
**Third** the image is **not** a camera picture is just like a person icon.
Use as follow and you will see:

```
Container(
        height: 120.0,
        width: 120.0,
        color: Colors.yellow,
        child: SvgPicture.asset('assets/camera.svg'),
      )
```

I put a Yellow color background to show a better result.
Hope this help.

Comment: Yup! flutter_svg does not support `<style>` elements.

Answer (score 3):

Even I faced this problem in flutter, the problem is with the SVG file and I cleaned the SVG file using this website https://jakearchibald.github.io/svgomg/  and it worked well then.

Comment: this worked for me, but the color is black for some reason while the actual svg has white color with blue inside. If i change the color it changes color for the entire thing.

Answer (score 2):

Please follow below steps to resolve this error:

1. copy your svg picture code.
2. convert your svg code to inline CSS using this tool [css-inliner](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/resources/tools/css-inliner/)
3. paste your new svg code to the existing svg file
4. restart the app, this will resolve your problem.

This is because the [flutter_svg](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_svg) package does not render the internal CSS of your svg code.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing you have to do buddy! just open that svg file in your android studio. and remove style attribute from there.

Comment: Please no image of code : https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question

Answer (score 0):

After trying a lot of options resizing using this site https://www.iloveimg.com/resize-image/resize-svg solved the issue. It will generate the new svg and style is all inline.

Answer (score 0):

```
I Solve this problem by removing this part : 
 <defs>
    <style>
        .cls-1{}
    </style>
</defs>
```

and add fill:"#hexColor" inside path
for example :

> 

```
   <path id="Path_2"fill="#17be78"
```