# Flutter - SVG file's stroke becomes more thin

Tags: flutter, svg, dart, flutter-layout

I have an SVG type file. I want to show it in my Flutter app using [`flutter_svg`](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_svg) package. But when I imported it, the color turns into black.

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62748027), I 'm using [this software](https://github.com/RazrFalcon/svgcleaner-gui/releases) to clean it.

For some files, it's worked really well. But, I have an issue with this file.

When I'm trying to show it in my app, the stroke width decreased and my SVG becomes really thin.

This is what I want:

[image: What I want]

But, this is what I've got:

[image: What I got]

*Does anyone have an idea how to solve this?*

**ATTACHMENT:** [This is the SVG file link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/13HZqfHHdJ3QPjJk-GT1V0YOcUhxyU9hx/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58425258/5362583

Comment: @Alok I've done that. And it can't always render the SVG file properly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to create a path from the outline stroke line.

this is your svg: https://gist.github.com/kherel/02f288ecd73f0c29a04b1f2d9c5db3e3
I've used [figma](http://figma.com)

[image]
[image]